# What does the + mean in Python string slices?

Tags: python

I just starting to learn Python and have been following the Google Python class. In one of the string exercises, there is this code:

```
def not_bad(s):
  n = s.find('not')
  b = s.find('bad')
  if n != -1 and b != -1 and b > n:
    s = s[:n] + 'good' + s[b+3:]
  return s
```

I was wondering what the s[b+3:] stands for, as it is the first time I have come across the + within a string slice.

Comment: It's nothing special to do with slicing.  `b+3` in a slice means the same thing that `b+3` would mean anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` is just the addition operator, which adds the value of `b` with `3`. It is used in this case, to skip the three characters `bad`.

`s[:n]` keeps all the characters till `not`, `+ 'good' +`, `s[b+3:]` all the characters after `bad`.

Answer (score 2):

It's just another expression. `s[b+3:]`, equivalent to `s[(b+3):]`, means the portion of `s` starting three characters from the position `b`.